# How to get MIME-type using Zend Framework 1?

Tags: php, zend-framework

I want to download a file using Zend Framework 1.
The file is currently located at my local disk.

My downloadAction looks somewhat like this:

```
public function downloadAction() {
    header('Content-Type: some/contentType');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="myFile.ext"');
    readfile('path/to/myFile.ext');

    // disable layout and view
    $this->view->layout()->disableLayout();
    $this->_helper->viewRenderer->setNoRender(true);
}
```

(see also http://www.stoimen.com/blog/2010/05/25/download-files-with-zend-framework/)

Is it possible to add automatic MIME detection of the file **without** having magic_mime module or fileinfo module installed?

Answer (score 0):

The short answer to your question is "no", but the fileinfo extension is bundled with PHP as of version 5.3.0. If you are using a version older than that then you have bigger problems.

Comment: I recently installed XAMPP for Windows v1.8.2 (which includes PHP5.4) However when using the fileinfo module, my browser reports this error: "Fatal error: Call to undefined function finfo_open()"

Comment: In that case, open your php.ini file and look for the line `extension=php_fileinfo.dll`. If it's commented out, uncomment it, then restart the web server.